# How to break out of PHP script during Ajax call and fire jQuery error handler with error?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to be able to break out of my PHP script that is called with jQuery Ajax. How can I return an error back to jQuery to display to the user?

PHP:

```
if($gift_card != null)
{
echo "not null";            
}
else 
{
echo "null";    
exit();         
}
```

jQuery:

```
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        status.html("There was an error processing the request. " + errorThrown);  
                        setTimeout(function() {                                
                            status.fadeOut(); 
                        }, 4000);                            
                    },
                    success: function( data ) {
                        if (console && console.log){
                            console.log( 'Sample of data:', data);
                        }                            
                        status.html('Email Sent Successfully.');   
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            status.fadeOut(); 
                        }, 4000);
```

If I echo null and exit, it is still coming back as success. Do I just have to check the data in success and see what is returned and then go from there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if I am not mistaken, if your php header result code is anything other than 200 , it will be treated as an error by the jquery $.ajax .

Comment: Makes sense. I think it's considered a success, even though I'm thinking of it as an error. So I believe, I have to check the data that is returned and and make adjustments there.

Answer (score 2):

The 'Success' in ajax refers to the success of the php being run. The way I usually do it is with:

Successs: function(data)
                  {
                   if(data=="null")
                   {
                       }
                       else if (data=="not null")
                   {
                       }
                       else
                       {
                       }
                 }

Sorry it's not in code format. I'm on my droid.

Answer (score 2):

I consider signaling an ajax error via HTTP status codes to be improper behavior. My preferred method is to return a json structure which embedds status information, regardless of what happened on the PHP side of things.

```
$data = array(
   'error' => false,
   'message' => 'Everything A-OK',
   'error_code' => ...,
   'data' => actual response stuff here
);
echo json-encode($data);
```

or

```
$data = array(
   'error' => 'true',
   'message' => 'Database query failed',
   'error_code' => something relevant
);
echo json-encode($data);
```

That way, HTTP status codes will truly tell the ajax client that something blew up at the http level, and leaves the results of the ajax call at a higher level to be deal with.

People will argue this both ways, saying it's appropriate for an AJAX call to get a 404 response if the ajax request didn't produce any results. But that's like telling your wife that the grocery store doesn't exist because they were out of milk when you drove over to pick some up. Umm, no.. the store's there, the store worked fine. They're just out of stock.

Answer (score 1):

once the php process is called then you are not going to hit the error handler in jquery (unless you don't return the expected data type ie. json etc etc).

so you need the php script to echo out a string and catch that in your success handler.

Comment: This is not true, if you return anything higher than 400 as a status code, the error handler will be hit.

Comment: dagnamit - thought the etc etc would have covered that ;)